# Match a RegExp With Parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, telegram

How Can I Match This Regular expression?

```
ghgdfgfd(bbb)
```

I used This:

```
bot.onText(/\ghgdfgfd(bbb)/
```

But this does not work for me.

Comment: `(` has special meaning in regex. You will have to escape it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Comment: What is the purpose of that initial backslash in your regex?

Comment: Appriciate it, Thank you and @Robby Cornelissen my a awnser is `/\ghgdfgfd\(bbb\)/`

Comment: Thank you @Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the parentheses, otherwise they're interpreted as grouping operators:

```
/ghgdfgfd\(bbb\)/
```

Comment: Should this not be a comment?

Comment: @Rajesh It's a complete answer to the question, why should it?

Comment: Because this is a very common problem and there are many posts on how to escape special  characters  and should be marked as duplicate

Comment: @Rajesh Agree about the marking as duplicate. That's different from it having to be a comment though.

Comment: My point was instead of answering, you should have added a comment and then mark it as duplicate. Answering a basic problem will encourage people to post question without searching.

Comment: @Rajesh Fair point. After you sought out the duplicate, I voted to close as duplicate as well.